# How to inner join 3 tables using mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have joined two tables as below correctly

```
SELECT m.id as mid, c.id as cid FROM members m inner join companies c on m.id=c.id
```

and then I wanted to add a 3rd table also, but I can not get it working.

```
SELECT m.id as mid, c.id as cid, u.id as uid FROM members m inner join companies c on m.id=c.id inner join users u on m.id=u.id
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: We don't know. What do you have, and what are you looking for?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Isn't it funny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch them from inner joins to left joins.

If you use the inner join, and a result does not exist in all three tables, it will be excluded, appearing to fail/not return results.

```
SELECT m.id as mid, c.id as cid, u.id as uid 
FROM members m 
left join companies c on m.id=c.id 
left join users u on m.id=u.id
```

That should take care of all the issues you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a possibility of listing all the uid and cid under one column ?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: @Kaoukkos do you have an example of uid and cid under one column? Do you mean string concatenation, or do you want an if then statement?

Answer (score 0):

You're sharing your "id" column in Members with both users and companies, was this your intention? Really your tables should have differing IDs and only join on foreign keys.

e.g.

Members.id = 12345
Members.CompanyFk = 45632

Companies.id = 45632

Join members.companyfk to companies.id

Comment: I'm betting this is precisely it.  Normally, the company id of a member won't be called m.id, it would be called something like m.company_id.  It sounds like the OP is trying to join member ids, company ids, and user ids all together instead of, for example, a user id in the member table to the user id in the users table.